Write to BigQuery Time column from pyspark
I have bigquery table with column type TIME. I am trying to insert data in it from pyspark.
From the documentation, it says:


Spark string can be written to an existing BQ TIME column provided it is in the format for BQ TIME literals.


But I am unable to write df to table. For test I created a BQ table like:
CREATE TABLE `test_project.test_dataset.time_test` (name STRING, wake_up_time TIME)

And df in pyspark like:
schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("wake_up_time", StringType(), True)
])

data = [
    ("Alice", "10:00:00"),
    ("Bob", "11:00:00"),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

And when I write to BQ using:
(
    df
    .write
    .format("bigquery")
    .option("temporaryGcsBucket", "temp_bucket")
    .option("table", "test_project.test_dataset.time_test")
    .option("writeMethod", "direct")
    .mode("append")
    .save()
)

It throws exception:
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Provided Schema does not match Table test_project.test_dataset.time_test. Field wake_up_time has changed type from TIME to STRING
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job.reload(Job.java:419)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job.waitFor(Job.java:252)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClient.createAndWaitFor(BigQueryClient.java:179)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.finishedJob$lzycompute$1(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:185)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.finishedJob$1(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:185)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.$anonfun$loadDataToBigQuery$3(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logInfo(Logging.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logInfo$(Logging.scala:59)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.logInfo(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:33)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.loadDataToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:187)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.writeDataFrameToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:122)
    ... 53 more

I also tried using Timestamp but no luck. Interestingly, when I read data it returns LongType for time column. I tried using long as well but it also didn't work.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

In your bigquery table you declare "wake_up_time" as a TIME type :
CREATE TABLE `test_project.test_dataset.time_test` (name STRING, wake_up_time TIME)

but in your pyspark dataframe your wake_up_time column has a string type :
StructField("wake_up_time", StringType(), True)

So maybe try considering a datetime datatype for your wake_up_time column in your dataframe like timestamp:
StructField("wake_up_time", TimestampType(), True)


As I mentioned in the question, I already tried that and it didn't work:
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Provided Schema does not match Table test_project.test_dataset.time_test. Field wake_up_time has changed type from TIME to TIMESTAMP

@WaqarAhmed Can you try with DateType() then?

@VikasSharma Already tried. Didn't work either.
